# UFW: Weird incomming request from router and other home pc

Tags: server, ssh, raspberrypi, ufw

This morning I finished setting up raspberry pi os. I also set up my ufw.

Now when I check my logs I see this weird incomming blocked request. These ip addresses are from my router, my own laptop and sometimes another home pc.

here is an example:

```
Jul  9 11:36:07 raspberrypi kernel: [ 9433.861599] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= SRC=x.x.x.x DST=224.0.0.251 LEN=32 TOS=0x00 PREC=0xC0 TTL=1 ID=0 DF PROTO=2
```

Does anybody know why I keep getting these requests around every 3 minutes, and is it something to worry about?